# Background with linear-gradient change color according to the specific page

Tags: html, css, background

I am making a website and I want each page to fade from black to a different color in every page. I know I can do a separate div for each page in the website and include it as a background. Is there a way to do it in the body tag directly? without doing a div for every page?

To clarify: If i am in the home page i want it to fade from black to light blue.  If i am in the history page i want it to fade from black to yellow.

This is the body tag in my CSS file:

```
body{
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #5DBCD2, 15%, black);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
  }
```

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need a way to differentiate each page for your CSS to know which color to apply, adding a class to the body tag would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `class` to the `body` every page like `home`, `history`

```
body{
    font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
body.home{
   background: linear-gradient(to top, #5DBCD2, 15%, black);
}
body.history{
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #5DBCD2, 15%, black);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

Give each page `body` a class and then use CSS Custom Properties to set the color for each class.

Your CSS would be something like

```
:root {
--color-start: green;
}

body{ /* this is the default */
  background: linear-gradient(to top, var(--color-start), 15%, black);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
  }

.home {
--color-start: red
}

.history {
--color-start:blue
}
```